# Java String, single char to hex bytes

Tags: java, hex

I want to convert a string by single char to 5 hex bytes and a byte represent a hex number:

like

```
String s = "ABOL1";
```

to

```
byte[] bytes = {41, 42, 4F, 4C, 01}
```

I tried following code , but `Byte.decode` got error when string is too large, like "4F" or "4C". Is there another way to convert it?

```
String s = "ABOL1";
char[] array = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  String hex = String.format("%02X", (int) array[i]);
  bytes[i] = Byte.decode(hex);
}
```

Comment: A `char` is not a `byte`!

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex byte'. The data is already in the format you require. Just copy the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String hex = String.format("0x%02X", (int) array[i]);` to specify HexDigits with `0x` before the string.

A better solution is convert `int` into `byte` directly:

```
bytes[i] = (byte)array[i];
```

Answer (score 5):

Is there any reason you are trying to go through string? Because you could just do this:

```
bytes[i] = (byte) array[i];
```

Or even replace all this code with:

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert from `char` to hex `String` with [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) array[i]);
```

Or threat the `char` as an `int` and use:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString((int) array[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The [Byte.decode() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode-java.lang.String-) specifies that hex numbers should be on the form `"0x4C"`. So, to get rid of the exception, try this:

```
String hex = String.format("0x%02X", (int) array[i]);
```

There may also be a simpler way to make the conversion, because the String class has a method that converts a string to bytes :

```
bytes = s.getBytes();
```

Or, if you want a raw conversion to a byte array:

```
int i, len = s.length();
byte bytes[] = new byte[len];
String retval = name;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) name.charAt(i);
}
```